# Py3o in Odoo 10

Tags: templates, reporting, odoo-10

Anybody has an experience how to pass an SQL query and iterate it in Py3o? If I have an self._cr.fetchall() result from Odoo function, how can I work with it in Py3o template?

Comment: Can you provide an example, or some example code, see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Yes, let´s say I have following SQL statement which I need to pass and iterate in Py3o template in Libre Office:select
  m.period_id as period,
  m.date as date,
  p.name as partner_name,
  p.vat as VAT,
  m.name as name,
  m.tax_deduct as tax,
  m.tax_base as tax_bas,
  'Tax deduct' as type
from
  account_move m
left join
  res_partner p
on
  m.partner_id = p.id
where
  m.tax_deduct != 0
  and m.period_id IN (63)